# Fullcalendar Resourse Timeline View with reactjs - Change the slots color

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

If I add an event in the 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek' views, I only see it in there. If I change to 'resourceTimelineWeek' or 'resourceTimelineDay' views, I can not see the event.

But my main problem, is that I try to make every slot in the 'resourceTimelineWeek' view to have a color, and when is clicked I want to change the color. I want it to seem like a booking calendar.
This is my code, which was written by many online sources:

```
const BookingPage = () => {

  const [calendarState, setCalendarState] = useState({
    weekendsVisible: true,
    currentEvents: []
  })
  const handleDateSelect = (selectInfo) => {
    let title = prompt('Please enter a new title for your event')
    let calendarApi = selectInfo.view.calendar
    calendarApi.unselect() // clear date selection
    if (title) {
      calendarApi.addEvent({
        id: createEventId(),
        title,
        start: selectInfo.startStr,
        end: selectInfo.endStr,
        allDay: selectInfo.allDay
      })
    }
  }
  const handleEventClick = (clickInfo) => {
    if (window.confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete the event '${clickInfo.event.title}'`)) {
      clickInfo.event.remove()
    }
  }
  const handleEvents = (events) => {
    setCalendarState({
      ...calendarState,
      currentEvents: events
    })
  }
  const renderEventContent = (eventInfo) => {
    return (
      <>
        <b>{eventInfo.timeText}</b>
        <i>{eventInfo.event.title}</i>
      </>
    )
  }
  return (
    <div className={`${styles['seats-calendar']}`}>
      <div className={`${styles['inner']}`}>
        <h1 className={`${styles['title']}`}>Calendar Overview</h1>
        <FullCalendar
          plugins={[interactionPlugin, resourceTimelinePlugin, dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin,]}
          headerToolbar={{
            left: 'prev',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'next,customWeeks,dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,resourceTimelineWeek'
          }}
          initialView='customWeeks'
          views={{
            customWeeks:{
              type: 'resourceTimeline',
              duration: { weeks: 2 },
              slotDuration: {days: 1},
              buttonText: 'Custom Week'
            }
          }}
          events={{
            display: 'background'
          }}
          resourceAreaWidth='80px'
          weekNumbers={true}
          resourceAreaHeaderContent= ' '
          display_mode={{
            tooltip: true
          }}
          resources={[
            { id: 'a', title: 'a' },
            { id: 'b', title: 'b' },
            { id: 'c', title: 'c' },
            { id: 'd', title: 'd' },
            { id: 'e', title: 'e' },
            { id: 'f', title: 'f' },
            { id: 'g', title: 'g' },
            { id: 'h', title: 'h' },
            { id: 'i', title: 'i' },
            { id: 'j', title: 'j' },
            { id: 'k', title: 'k' },
            { id: 'l', title: 'l' },
            { id: 'm', title: 'm' },
            { id: 'n', title: 'n' },
            { id: 'o', title: 'o' },
            { id: 'p', title: 'p' },
            { id: 'q', title: 'q' },
            { id: 'r', title: 'r' },
            { id: 's', title: 's' },
            { id: 't', title: 't' },
            { id: 'u', title: 'u' },
            { id: 'v', title: 'v' },
            { id: 'w', title: 'w' }
          ]}
          editable={true}
          selectable={true}
          selectMirror={true}
          dayMaxEvents={true}
          weekends={calendarState.weekendsVisible}
          initialEvents={INITIAL_EVENTS} // alternatively, use the `events` setting to fetch from a feed
          select={handleDateSelect}
          eventContent={renderEventContent} // custom render function
          eventClick={handleEventClick}
          eventsSet={handleEvents} // called after events are initialized/added/changed/removed
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default BookingPage;
```

The result is this, which is what I want, but when the promt appears and I add an event, nothing changes.
[image]

If I do the same thing at the dayGridMonth view, the result is this:
[image]

These examples are here just to show my code and what happens.
The thing that I need most, is to be able to change the slots color and when I click them to change again, but in the custom view (it's resourceTimeline view with specific days and weeks).

Comment: If you add an event without specifying a resourceId for that event, it will not show up in any resource-aware view. The reason for this should be self-evident - how would fullCalendar know which resource to show it on, if it doesn't have a resourceId? Obviously it doesn't know, so it can't display it. There isn't a space at the bottom for non-resource events in those views.

Comment: And if you want an event to "change the slot colour" as you describe it, then give the event the display property with value "background" , as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events

Comment: I don't actually need the events. I want to have a color on all the slots and when I click one, to change it, like I booked the date. I just used the events example because I could not find an other way to do it.

Comment: Background events is the exact way to do what you're suggesting

Comment: Ok I will check it out. Thanks.